# Doing some clean-up after client request fully served, in c# ASP.net MVC, how?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task

lets assume I have an action like:

```
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        // Doing user register
        user_register();   // take almost no time
        // doing some stats and other clean up
        more_clean_up();   // take few seconds
        return View();
    }
```

here is what I want to achieve:

```
        user_register();
        return View();
        more_clean_up();
```

I know above code won't work, more_clean_up(); will never be executed. 
Since more_clean_up(); task is not important for the view(), also it take time, so I want to it execute some way not block current users view experience.

I know a way to open another thread or go async, but I more prefer if here is a way to:

```
doing_some_render_for_client();
Response.Flush();
**disconnect_from_client();**
more_clean_up();
```

Does anyone know how to disconnect_from_client(); but not terminate like ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); does

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into spawning a new thread for this using [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbf0f1ct.aspx). Simply give it your `more_clean_up` method (you'll have to make sure it has single `object` parameter)  and you should be all set.

To answer your second question more specifically - No, you really shouldn't be trying to do that.